# Regex: Match the word but no 'alphabet' after it except for 's'

Tags: regex, scala, regex-lookarounds

The string I want to match shouldn't have a following alphabetical letter except for 's' but it can have any following digit or symbol.

**Note**: Any alphabetical letter are allowed after the string but must have preceding whitespace/symbol.

For the root `msl`,
**Should match**: `msl`, `msls`, `msl123`, `msl123s`, `mslss`, `mslss xxx`, `x_msl`, `x_msl_x`
**Shouldn't match**: `msled`, `mslsxxx`, `xmsl_x`

```
 "msl" matches ".*" + "word_msl" + "(What Regex to put here?).*"
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you post some more examples and their expected outputs?

Comment: @Potato is it clear now?

Comment: @ikegami how about now

Comment: @data-maniac Try this [`^msl(?:s|[^a-rt-z]*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/HVXG4Q/2)

Comment: @Potato I tried this `"msl aa" matches ".*" + "msl" + "(?:s|[^a-rt-z]*)$.*"` but getting false. But `mslsx, msls` works. So your is partially right. Can you try one more time to make that work?

Comment: @ikegami Not no.1 because it has characters right after s but no. 2, 3, 4 are fine.

Comment: @data-maniac; I've added 2 **should** examples (adapted from your original posting) and one **shouldn't** example. Please verify that all current examples are labeled (should/shoudn't) correctly.

Comment: @ikegami; But that's how this question began. Look at the **True examples** from the original posting.

Comment: @jwvh, And it still says "word_msl" instead of "msl". Reverted my reversion, and edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[*The question originally had [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) as a tag*]

```perl
my $root = "msl";

/
   (?<![^\s_])                    # At the start of a "word" or after a "_"
   \Q$root\E                      # Match the value of $root literally
   (?: \S* s                      # Non-whitespace characters ending with "s", or
   |   [^\ss]*                    # Non-whitespace, non-"s" characters
   )
   (?!\S)                         # At the end of a "word"
/x
```

Optimized:

```perl
my $root = "msl";

/
   (?<![^\s_])                    # At the start of a "word" or after a "_"
   \Q$root\E                      # Match the value of $root literally
   [^\ss]*+                       # Non-whitespace, non-"s" characters
   (?: s (?: [^\ss]*+ s )*+ )?+   # Optionally, non-whitespace characters ending with "s"
   (?!\S)                         # At the end of a "word"
/x
```

In this case, a "word" is considered to be a sequence of non-whitespace characters delimited by whitespace, the start of the string and/or the end of the string.

Comment: what language is this? how do I use this in scala?

Comment: huh, this is written in one of the languages you tagged.

Comment: Can u do java, i did for perl engine, coz it has similarity